# How to make "gather" live together with my custom processing of the text?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

This is the code that doesn't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{+b}
  {\tl_set:Nn\l__foo_tmp_tl{#1}}
  {\regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
  \l__foo_tmp_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{foo}
first \\ second \\ third
\end{foo}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to do pre-processing of the text before it gets into the `gather` environment. If I replace `gather` with `equation`, the code compiles.

Comment: it's hard to see what you want here `\begin{equation}{ a }\end{equation}` is not an error, `\begin{gather}{ a\\b}\end{gather}` is an error as you can not start a group in one cell and end another, so the definition of `foo` does not matter, you can not have an environment there

Comment: you could of course re-inject `\l__foo_tmp_tl` after the group leaving an empty group in the first cell but that would be weird syntax, with `foo` not grouping its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expand a global token list after `foo` has ended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__foo_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N \g__foo_tmp_tl

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{b}
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l__foo_tmp_tl {#1}
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
   \tl_gset_eq:NN \g__foo_tmp_tl \l__foo_tmp_tl
   \group_insert_after:N \g__foo_tmp_tl
  }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{foo}
first \\ second \\ third
\end{foo}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd define a `foogather` environment.

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foogather}{b}
  {
   \tl_set:Nn \l__foo_tmp_tl {#1}
   \regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
   \begin{gather}
   \tl_use:N \l__foo_tmp_tl
   \end{gather}
  }{}
```

Note that `+b` is wrong, because `gather` doesn't accept blank lines.

Comment: so  slow:-).......

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But using the proper `expl3` syntax.

Comment: what's an aftergroup between friends:-)  (I think you are missing an `\end{gather}` )

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you really want this you need to lift the definitions out of the environment, but not using environment syntax would be simpler to understand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N\l__foo_tmp_tl
\tl_new:N\g__foo_tmp_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn {Nx}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{+b}
  {\tl_set:Nn\l__foo_tmp_tl{#1}}
  {\regex_replace_all:nnN {e}{X} \l__foo_tmp_tl
   \tl_gset_eq:NN\g__foo_tmp_tl\l__foo_tmp_tl
  \aftergroup\g__foo_tmp_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{foo}
first \\ second \\ third
\end{foo}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```